# Acumatica Missing Framework Item Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2015, frameworks, acumatica

After re-running "**Deploy Acumatica Framework Tools**", the message shows up that the zip files existed and asked me to over-write.

I Responded with Yes.  Finished OK.

Now only `PXGraph` shows up and none of the other items are available.

After looking around the file system it I believe the zip files are in place.

Why would Visual Studio not be able to find these templates?  How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Acumatica has a PDF named "ConfiguringDevEnvironment" that accompanies the development courses in Acumatica Open University. (Registration is free.) Near the end of this document there's a section that describes how to configure the solution in MS Visual Studio. A screenshot near the end shows the solution structure with a C# Class Library project and the Acumatica web site as its immediate children. The website has a new folder under the web site's Pages folder for the solution.

Once the Acumatica Framework Tools are deployed and the solution is configured this way, adding a new item to the C# Class Library project shows the PXGraph item template but none of the other Acumatica item templates. Adding a new item to the folder under the website Pages does not show PXGraph, but does show the other Acumatica item templates: FormDetail, FormTab, FormView, ListView, TabDetail, and TabView.

The Acumatica Framework Tools' item templates are deployed to Documents\[VSVersion]\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C# as .zip files. [VSVersion] is the currently supported version for the version of Acumatica, for example, Visual Studio 2015 for Acumatica 6.x.